Sharing on WhatsApp does not include all the text
I have a static react native app. It has a section for different topics to share. Some topics are lengthy upto 6000 or 7000 characters. When I share the topic on emulator(using Messages App) it includes all the text. but when I try this on my mobile phone(especially on WhatsApp), it doesn't include the full text.
If I share the topic on Messages app or notepad on my mobile it works fine.
I wanted to know is there any limit to sharing on WhatsApp or I'm doing something wrong.
I tried consoling the text before sharing it is fine. I don't what's the issue here.

Welcome to SO, Can you add a Minimal Reproducible Example
